# Scale a Bezier Curve Proportionally - calculate control points

Tags: ios, core-graphics, shapes

I'm trying to take a bezier curve (any arbitrary curve in Core Graphics) and shrink (or expand) it proportionally given another two end points.  I have an approach that sort of works, but it ends up 'flattening' out the curves, and not retaining the shape exactly.  Maybe I've messed up the code or logic, but I have the two original points along with the control point(s).  Given another set of end points I want to calculate the appropriate control points to produce the same shape between the new end points.

Here's the main code that will calculate 1 control point:

```
CGPoint (^ScaledCtrlPoint)(CGPoint, CGPoint, CGPoint, CGPoint, CGPoint) = ^CGPoint (CGPoint refPoint1, CGPoint refPoint2, CGPoint bevPoint1, CGPoint bevPoint2, CGPoint ctrlPoint){
        //Normalize points to refPoint1
        refPoint2.x -= refPoint1.x; refPoint2.y -= refPoint1.y;
        ctrlPoint.x -= refPoint1.x; ctrlPoint.y -= refPoint1.y;
        //Normalize bevPoints to bevPoint1
        bevPoint2.x -= bevPoint1.x; bevPoint2.y -= bevPoint1.y;
        //Calculate control point angle
        CGFloat theta = PointTheta(refPoint2);
        CGFloat refHyp = (refPoint2.y != 0.0f) ? refPoint2.y / sinf(theta) : refPoint2.x / cosf(theta);
        theta = PointTheta(bevPoint2);
        CGFloat bevHyp = (bevPoint2.y != 0.0f) ? bevPoint2.y / sinf(theta) : bevPoint2.x / cosf(theta);
        theta = PointTheta(ctrlPoint);
        CGFloat ctrlHyp = (ctrlPoint.y != 0.0f) ? ctrlPoint.y / sinf(theta) : ctrlPoint.x / cosf(theta);
        ctrlHyp *= (bevHyp / refHyp);
        return CGPointMake(bevPoint1.x + cosf(theta) * ctrlHyp, bevPoint1.y + sinf(theta) * ctrlHyp);
    };
```

The `bevPoints` are the new points I'm using to calculate the new control point.  The `refPoints` and `ctrlPoint` are the original points of the bezier curve.  As you can see, I'm trying to scale the ctrlPoint down (could also work up) by the same ratio as the the original end points are to the new end points.

I also use another function, which I use to calculate incident angles.  It's pretty simple:

```
CGFloat         PointTheta(CGPoint point){
    //This assumes an origin of {0, 0} and returns a theta for the given point
    CGFloat theta = atanf(point.y / point.x);
    //Using arc tan requires some adjustment depending on the point quadrant
    if (point.x == 0.0f) theta = (point.y >= 0.0f) ? M_PI_2 : M_PI + M_PI_2;
    else if (point.x < 0.0f) theta += M_PI;
    else if (point.x > 0.0f && point.y < 0.0f) theta += (M_PI * 2);
    return theta;
}
```

Comment: "shrink it proportionally given another two end points" - what does this mean? Any arbitrary 2 points? i.e.. curve will be rotated, scaled and translated?

Comment: Well, technically I suppose my question would include all three: scale, rotation and translation.  But practically I'm not rotating, only scaling and translating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would compute the `CGAffineTransform` with parameters

```
(a, b, -b, a, tx, ty)
```

(i.e. a transform without skewing) that maps the old endpoints to the new endpoints, and then apply this transform to the old control point to get the new control point.

The condition that the 2 old endpoints are mapped to the 2 new endpoints gives 4 equations for a, b, tx, ty, and these equations can even be solved without trigonometric functions.

Comment: Sorry, but I've only applied the `CGAffineTransform` functions to Views, Contexts, and CGPathRefs...I'm not sure how to apply them directly to individual points or even a `CGPathElement`, which is where I'm getting my original CGPoints from.  I see there is a `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` but the docs seem deficient. Where exactly does 'scaling' and 'rotation' (though I'm not personally rotating) occur around, `{0, 0}`?

Comment: A `CGAffineTransform` is a combination of translation, scaling, rotation and optionally skewing. I will try to make my answer more explicit as soon as I have time.

Comment: Yep, I confirmed it scales and rotates a point around the origin, `{0, 0}` when you apply a transform to a `CGPoint`.  So you need to normalize the point before apply the transform.  I modified my code to scale and translate the ctrl point using `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` and now everything works (and looks) great.  Thanks!