# Scale Bezier Curve

Tags: shapes, bezier

I need to adjust the length of a (cubic) Bezier curve to match that of another one, without disturbing its overall shape. This involves, I guess, proportionately scaling it recursively until the length is of the right magnitude (or is there any better approach?).

I have got the function that calculates the length. For scaling, I am stuck at calculating the coordinates of the new control points. There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264741/scale-a-bezier-curve-proportionally-calculate-control-points)  that seems to have the answer but I am unable to figure out to what the variables a, b etc. refer in the answer. Also, I need to write a function from scratch, without having recourse to any API library (except python math).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoting the length of your curve by *L* and the desired length *D*, it seems to me that you just need to scale your curve *(D/L)*-times. Thanks to [affine invariance](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-prop.html), it should be enough to scale all your control points. That is, multiply each coordinate of each of your control points by *D/L*.

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have been splitting and calculating Ts of the curves all this time. So it's become difficult for me to think that something about the Bezier curve can change in arithmetic proportion :)